# Beltrami's Essay on the Interpretation of non-Euclidean Geometry

Tags: mathematics, geometry, translations

I am reading the Essay of the title written by Beltrami in Italian and I found a specific point of the essay which in my opinion could be fully clarified only if compared with its translations. At the moment, I do not have access to Stillwell's translation for example, so I am asking here in case someone has it.

I am looking for the translation of the little paragraph just after Beltrami computes the formula for the geodetic arch $\sigma$, which you can find at page 7 in its Italian version [here](http://www.caressa.it/pdf/beltrami01.pdf).

Comment: I see it in Google books.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I didn't think I would be able to find it there. Thank you!